# Heroku PHP hosting timeout

Tags: php, heroku, background, timeout, facebook-apps

I am currently hosting a research project on Heroku using PHP and the Facebook API. It is somewhat intensive, so it is running past Heroku's time limit of 30 seconds for a response. Using their support, they suggest to use a background process to do this (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing), but they don't say how I should do this for PHP. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Symfony 2 process component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/process.html). Its got a nice and simple OO interface for working with processes.

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpProcess;

$command = file_get_contents('/hello_world.php');

if ( $command ) {
    $process = new PhpProcess($command);
    $process->run();

    if ($process->isSuccessful()) {

        $output = $process->getOutput();
        // ... 
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception($process->getErrorOutput());
    }
}
```

Comment: So I just include the code I am using now in a file, in your example hello_world.php, and then just call it like you said and it shouldn't give me a time out? Do I need to install Symfony 2 on Heroku or would that already be available?

Comment: You would need to [install the process compontent](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/process.html) into your project. You do not need the whole symfony2 framework. You can either clone the [git repo](https://github.com/symfony/Process) or use [composer](https://packagist.org/).

Comment: where do you place the downloaded files please? I keep on getting Class Symfony\Component\Process\PhpProcess not found error.